# Loading scripts in bootstrap framework

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm following this tutorial here: http://www.jingpingji.com/blog/2015/8/4/transferring-sound-data-with-binaryjs-and-buffering-for-smooth-playbac

which uses binary.js and the Web Audio API to create an application that streams microphone audio to clients. I can't seem to get binary.js to work.

I did npm install binaryjs and then made a link to the path to binary.js on my HTML page.

Is there something I'm missing?

All my code after *require('binaryjs')* on my javascript files will cease to run.

Comment: if you using node module, you might try to use require("binary") as node doesn't requires file extensions

Comment: I just tried it. Still nothing. There has to be something I'm missing... I have binaryjs listed as a dependency on my package.json file, too, as such:

    "binaryjs": "^0.2.1"

Comment: I have seen it getting used as  require('binaryjs') as the package name is 'binaryjs', can you post code block that giving you error. Also in your original post you have require('binary.js') instead of require('binaryjs')

Comment: That was my mistake. Here is the code:   

    document.getElementById('start-rec-btn').addEventListener('click', 
    function() {
      var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
        if(BinaryServer) alert('success!')
    
    })

Comment: hmm.. why you using require('binaryjs').BinaryServer; on client..  require will work only on server unless your are using a module bundler.Here is the code to set up Binary.JS connection on the client side:  
var host = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws') + '/binary-endpoint';
var client = new BinaryClient(host);
You’ll also need to include the binary.js file in the html, like so:
<script src=“...your-path.../binary.js"></script>

Comment: I was able to get this to work. I think my path was incorrect. So when I install scripts like binaryjs, should I be linking them directly from node_modules when I make an application? I see other examples where they sit outside the directory and I wasn't sure if that is standard.

And thank you on the code set up. I was having trouble following along.

Comment: as long as you can access binary.js, it will not matter where it sits up...